# Fitting heat map from gnuplot to the frame size

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I have a minor problem with gnuplot. I have a heat-map (figure attached), and as you see the heat map does not fit the frame. Could you suggest me a way to fix this (other than zooming in of course, since I would be writing a script to copy the plots into a different folder and I do not want to manually fit the plots to the frames).

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: How does your minimal code and your data look like? This would help. Without knowing this, I would say set your `xrange` and `yrange` properly.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the axis ranges explicitly to match the map, or tell gnuplot to use auto-scaling but not extend the axis to the next tick mark:

```
  set xrange [*:*] noextend
  set yrange [*:*] noextend
```